# How to add id to a primary key in postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, unique-constraint

I'm trying to insert data into postges database in python.This is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fp_stores_data_test (
    time INTEGER,
    province VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    market_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    product_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER, 
    quantity INTEGER,
    has_sold INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (time, city, province, market_id ,product_id)
);
```

and this is my python function which tries to add data to database:

```py
def add_data_to_db(cursor, address):

    list_of_files = listdir(address)
    for file_ in list_of_files:
        f = open(address+file_, "r")
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(",")
            query = "INSERT INTO fp_stores_data_test "\
                    "VALUES ({},'{}','{}',{},{},{},{},{})"\
                    .format(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3]
                            ,data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7])
            cursor.execute(query)
            print(data)
```

but this error appears :

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "fp_stores_data_test_market_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (market_id)=(1) already exists.
```

I don't know how to get rid of that default id.

Comment: You defined unique constraint for field market_id, so you can insert only one row with market+id = 1 . Second row with same market_id cause to constraint violation error. I mean You not need unique constraints on marked_id & product_id, but unique index on combination of those fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain about the semantics in your database but if it is as I understand it then (to me) it is obvious that several different markets can handle the same product and also that each market can handle more than one product. If that is the case then neither `market_id` nor `product_id` should be declared `UNIQUE` in the table. `NOT NULL` is OK but also not necessary as they both are part of the primary key. Postgresql does not, as far as I know, allow `NULL` values in the primary key. Thus the table ought to be declared:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fp_stores_data_test (
    time INTEGER,
    province VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    market_id INTEGER,
    product_id INTEGER,
    price INTEGER, 
    quantity INTEGER,
    has_sold INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (time, city, province, market_id ,product_id)
);
```

If `market_id` and `product_id` refer to the id column in tables for markets and products and those id columns are in the primary key of resp. table, I would also argue for them both to be declared as `FOREIGN KEY`